# Canada Tourist Visa with few ties to home country

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, tourist-visas

I would like to visit Canada for 2 weeks for tourist purposes only. This is the first time I'm applying to Canada. In past, I have traveled EU in 2017 and England in 2018. I don't have any invitation letter from Canada although those other two visas I got with the invitation letter. I'm having a decent business going on here in India. I'm happy to book a return flight ticket and hotel booking in advance. In the proof of ties, I can show:-

1) Bank balance $10k
2) Travel History(EU / UK)
3) Business registration documents
4) Last 3 ITRs(last year ITR was 6lakh)
5) NOC from my business partners on my company's letterhead(and use business account during my stay in Canada)

I heard that my case is not that strong because:-
1) I don't have an Invitation letter
2) I don't have any property registered on my own name
3) I'm single(not married)
4) Sudden transfer from business account to saving account

Answer (score 1):

Not having an invitation letter is not a problem.  The vast majority of tourists come to Canada with no invitation letter.

The rest is about ties to your home country. Not being married is only a slight disadvantage- if you were married your wife would presumably come with you, so wouldn't be a tie.

Not owning property isn't an issue, but showing you have a place to live long-term would definitely be a good idea. You should also explain the transfer from your business account and have evidence to back up what you say, especially if that is what you are paying for the trip with.

I'm not an expert but I would say you have a decent chance.